# Fractions in InDesign : Typing (not ½ = Alt + 0189)

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting

I'm wondering of anyone knows how to easily type a fraction like this:

```
1
-
2
```

(but on one baseline). I appreciate the "proper" way is : ½ = Alt + 0189; but the client has specifically asked for the numerators stacked one upon the over.

The only logical thing I can think of is superscripting and tracking...

Comment: Those are called "stacked" or "nut" fractions. If changing the font (in general or for the fractions only) is possible, see http://unfocusedbrain.com/site/2015/06/13/fonts_with_vertically_stacked_unicode_vulgar_fractions/ for a short list. See also https://github.com/TiroTypeworks/Nutso

Comment: I thank you Good Sir/Madam. First question - so if there "correct answer" button I need to confirm your greatness, please advise.

Comment: @RadLexus you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Cai: actually, I feel changing to another font is not a great *general* solution.

Comment: It's still an answer though :) (and I don't think it's possible otherwise?)

Comment: Fair point Rad. Actually, I've already seen a flaw, some of the stacked fractions required are uncommon i.e. 7/8 etc.

Comment: Mike, what do you mean the numerator stacked one atop the other? Like straight line bar instead of diagonal?

Comment: @Ryan yes, the formatting on the question was messing with the example.

Comment: Yes @Cai is right, the formatting has gone amiss; it should be 1(top) _ 2 (bottom)

Comment: I use a free version of a script for fractions that I got from ( http://www.danrodney.com/scripts/properfraction.html ). It may be a stepping off point for figuring out one for the stacked style. The trick to the over/under fraction though is the centering: the "normal 1/2" style has the benefit of not needing to know what the width of the numerator and denominator are nor is there any need to adjust the rule width.

Comment: If you are going to be doing a lot of math (not just fractions), there may be plugins for this, also "typesetting math" might help, but it will get hairy pretty quickly. http://www.bookdesignmadesimple.com/typesetting-math-in-indesign/

Answer (score 2):

Stacked fractions aren't supported by InDesign's fraction making features. To get stacked (or nut) fractions you need a font that has the stacked fractions.

A list of some Google Fonts (all free) that you can use (thanks to @RadLexus):

> - [Coda – by Vernon Adams](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Coda)
> - [Telex – by Huerta Tipografica](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Telex)
> - [Arbutus Slab – by Karolina Lach](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Arbutus+Slab)
> - [Unica One – by Eduardo Tunni](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Unica+One)
> - [Concert One](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Concert+One)
> - [Cherry Swash – by Nataliya Kasatkina](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cherry+Swash)
> - [Economica – by Vicente Lamonaca](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Economica)
> - [Special Elite – by Astigmatic](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Special+Elite)

<sup>[Source](http://unfocusedbrain.com/site/2015/06/13/fonts_with_vertically_stacked_unicode_vulgar_fractions/)</sup>

What you can do is find a similar font and use a GREP style to change the font of the fractions. To create a GREP style to find fractions, you need to set the **To Text** field appropriately. Since `\d` stands for any digit, `\d/\d` will make it search for digit/digit.

It's not an ideal solution and it will depend on what actual fractions you need, the font you are using etc. But as far as I'm aware theres no alternative to do this automatically in InDesign.

#### Or—Make them yourself!

Another option, if your font has a full range of superscript and subscript numerals (or maybe even without, but this would be less ideal, as sup/sub numerals are designed to be shown at smaller sizes) is to use those with a dash (which one I'm not sure, experiment!) to build the fractions yourself. You can set up some GREP styles again to automatically set these to all your fractions.

I won't show you the exact styles because it will vary depending on the font etc, but I just set up some stacked fractions with 3 GREP styles: one for the denominator, one for the bar, and one for the numerator:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think Rad Lexus is correct but didn't give the full answer.

Don't use ascii (Alt + numbers) to create the fractions in InDesign. Use InDesign.

Good high quality fonts will have OpenType Fractions, which is different than just having a single fraction Glyph:

[image]

For example with Candara:

[image]

But then you'll have to find a high quality font that has a horizontal bar if that's what you're after. I'd start by contacting some good Font Foundry directly and see if they make one or could recommend one. House Industries is one that puts out really nice fonts IMO, not sure if any of theirs has a horizontal fraction style but you could ask them: http://www.houseind.com/